# Get data from Cache before server turns off

Tags: java, architecture, cache-control

Where does the cache (OScache or EHCache) runs on web/application server

If i have multiple servers on clustered environment, how to make sure to get the data from cache before the       application server 1 turns off and route it through another application server 2 .

E.g. if i have something in shopping cart and application server 1 crashes. How can i get the data from cache before the application server 1 crashes and save it through application server 2?

Comment: It seems to me that this requires you to `import java.prediction.future`. If a server crashes, I'd imagine it's too late to grab any data off of it. I'm also fairly certain that Java doesn't have facilities to manipulate information at that low of a level. I'm not even sure if you can directly read cache using any language.

Comment: Unless you're talking about backing up the contents of server 1 regularly to server 2, which is slightly different

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to answer this question. Unless you have some sort of **persistent** or **external** cache, the answer is that the data is stored in memory.

Comment: I thought Amazon may be using this kind of caching implementation when the app server crashes, was curious to know how they do it? I have also been asked the similar question in couple of interviews.

Comment: I think you're barking up the wrong tree here. For a small scale application (although not that small) you can use a database. For a large scale application you can use webserver clustering and session syncing. For a really large application then you might need to use something like Terracotta.

Comment: My question should have been like this "If i have clustered environment, how to make sure to get the data from cache before the cluster 1 turns off and get it from another cluster OR how the distributed cache works?                                                    Here is the link to check how distributed cache works                                      http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15357_01/coh.360/e15723/cache_intro.htm#BABJJJDI